# How to fix encoding while reading a CSV file?

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm reading a CSV file in php and so far as i have understood - these kind of files can have any encoding that was ever invented by hoomans *omg* and so on... i guess i have a MacRoman ANSI encoded CSV, i'm working on a Mac.

So far, so good (not good at all but thats another topic).. Now, while iterating through the lines, i have a value like:

```
Z�rich
```

Obviously, it should be "Zürich" - the "ü" is missing..

Now, i have tried almost anything.. mb_detect_encoding is saying "false" so, he doesn't understand what it is...

Then i have found a genius class by Sebastian Grignoli here -> [Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8)

Seems nice but... all i got is:

```
ZŸrich
```

not really the "ü" i have expected :D

Now i have found out, that a "utf8_encode" will work somehow, it generates:

```
Z\u009Frich
```

but.. what now? if i put this directly in the database, the final value is "Zrich", which means it is still not really UTF-8, or is the db just struggling with the escaped variant? When i make an mb_detect_encoding on that value, he says now "UTF-8".. nice.. but how can i go further? How can i get my "Zürich" the right way in UTF-8?

Comment: What's the encoding on the database column storing these values?

Comment: change the character set to utf8 when creating the table

Comment: in my application, everything is utf-8, from the table, to the code to the browser - everything.. the problem here occurs when i'm reading a file that is uploaded by a user, that was created by an MS Excel on any client machine, so, the file can be encoded in everything and i have no control about that :/
(source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508558/what-charset-does-microsoft-excel-use-when-saving-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use `iconv` for the conversion. On my installation, the MacRoman encoding is called simply `"MAC"`:

```
$city = "Z\x9frich";
$city = iconv("MAC", "UTF-8", $city); 
echo $city; // Output: Zürich
```

Comment: iconv is even able to directly correct the text from Z�rich to Zürich - but you have to know the encoding which is quite hard when mb_detect_encoding is always returning "false" -> so i wrote my own detect lik described here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: It's hard to distinguish between single-byte encodings because every byte sequence is valid, unlike in variable-byte encodings. If you don't have any information of the origin of the text you'll have to make a guess based on letter or n-gram frequencies for example.

Comment: sounds interesting, currently i have implemented already a kind of wild-guessing like described in the php doc comments, but i have to google about that stuff you write ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert all the file first with iconv. And import later.
Or iterate every line and convert with iconv.

You must know the original codification of your file.