# Excel exports CSV - what to do about HTML entities?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, html-entities

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I'm exporting as a CSV. HTML entities are being converted into a `?`. Is there a way to convert the spreadsheet into a CSV and convert those HTML entities into the CSV compatible counterpart?

My ultimate goal is to import the CSV into a MySQL database using a PHP script. The consumers of the data will mostly be using it within a web environment, but that's not necessarily true always.

Comment: How do you convert the Excel files?

Comment: I use Excel's "Save As" option.

Comment: What does PHP and MySQL have to do with your problem. then?

Comment: what is converting the 'HTML entities' php? excel?

Comment: When I save from Excel to CSV, the entities are converted into `?` already.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate your issue but nothing s far. Could you share some of the characters that are converting into `?`

Comment: The `em dash` character is the one I'm noticing right now. In the spreadsheet, it looks like `—` but turns to a `?` in the CSV.

Comment: your not actully meaning HTML entities, you don't have &.m.d.a.s.h.; in excel you have the utf8 or what ever encoding excel is using character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Save As` command is not working properly then you have some encoding problems. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508558/what-charset-does-microsoft-excel-use-when-saving-files)

Comment: Thanks. It was an encoding problem. I changed Excel to use UTF-8. All good now.