# read utf-8 CSV file into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I have been trying to figure out how to get a UTF-8 CSV that I downloaded into a DataFrame.  So far I have tried

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='utf8')
```

and it gives me garbage.  I am having success reading it in with

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

as suggested in this post

[Reading a UTF8 CSV file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python)

but it reads in this gigantic file and I cannot get it into a DataFrame.

I'm using python 3. Thanks for helping!

My specific error output is

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 3: invalid start byte'

And the file I am trying to work is one of the YEARLY CSV files downloaded from this link (not WEEKLY, I am not sure if weekly is a different format)

https://exporter.nih.gov/ExPORTER_Catalog.aspx?sid=2&index=0

Comment: Your first line (df = ...) should work. Can you be more specific about "garbage" you may just need to add another parameter for the data to parse correctly

Comment: Can you post a link to the file, some lines from it, or an example of the "garbage" that pandas gives you?

Comment: thanks, I posted my error and a link to the download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to the post at this question

['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000191/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x92-in-position-18-invalid-start-byte)

I thought I would try the fix that they suggested

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='cp1252')
```

and it worked! It's Windows codepage 1252...  not utf-8