# Pandas read_csv() doesn't work on CSV file in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv

I used Python2.7.10 before. Recently I change to python 3.6. However, when I want to import csv files it fails. My simple code is like this and I think it should work well in Python2.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

And the error returns like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What does this mean and how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

## Update

I've already solved it adding something like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data.csv',sep='\t',encoding='utf-16')
```

Although I still don't know why it works, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: What is the encoding of your CSV file?  Can you show a small sample CSV demonstrating the problem?

Comment: try passing `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"` as a parameter to `read_csv`

Comment: this is the list of endocings.use the one suits your data. __       
[unicodes link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: Sorry. Actually I have no idea what my CSV file encoding is. How can I check the encoding type? In fact, the data is downloaded from CSMAR, if you guys know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000191/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x92-in-position-18-invalid-start-byte)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. This post helped me

['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000191/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x92-in-position-18-invalid-start-byte)

and my encoding ended up being Windows codepage 1252

[read utf-8 CSV file into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549256/read-utf-8-csv-file-into-dataframe/48551278#48551278)

but your encoding could be anything...