# Uploading CSV - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 16: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to upload a csv file using pandas .read() function. But as you can see from my title this is what I get 
"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 16: invalid start byte"
And it's weird because from the same folder I was able to upload a different csv file without problems. 
Something that might have caused this is that the file was previously xlsx and I manually converted it to cvs?
Please Help
Python3

Comment: Never mind, I solved it by adding this pd.read_csv("filename.csv",encoding="Latin-1")

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000191/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x92-in-position-18-invalid-start-byte)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

pd.read_csv("filepath",encoding='cp1252').

This one should work as it worked for me.

Comment: This is not really a solution. What encoding you pick depends on the encoding of the file.

Comment: Ok. So how do you find the encoding of the file so that I may pick the respective encoding?

Comment: Well, this is a hard problem. It boils down to just guessing. Libraries like `chardet` can help with that.