# Error loading large csv file "'utf-8' codec can not decrypt" in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 GB csv file and I can not read that log file and give same error in both python and pandas code in my csv file, it is not a value of more than one column because there is only a single column value and All of my CSV values is number

```
with open("/Users/kiya/sep_sent.csv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
for i in f: 
   print(i.strip())
```

another method:

```
with open("/Users/kiya/sep_sent.csv",encoding='cp1252') as f:
    for i in f:
      print(i.strip())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiya/test8.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 159: character maps to <undefined>
```

pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/kiya/sep_sent.csv", encoding="utf-8")
print(df)
```

my csv value like:

```
0
0
0
....
5294751024
```

error:

```
0
0
0
0
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiya//test8.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 52: invalid start byte
```

Comment: I already tried that that method is not working

Comment: OK, now I need the csv file to help.

Comment: The size of the csv file is 1 GB

Comment: Try with somthing smaller .. see my comment below, your terminal is `cp1252` and in the csv file are utf-8 characters which are not printable in that terminal, now you got this exception only when printing.

Comment: Test your terminal encoding with `python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"`

Comment: i tested and its  UTF-8

Comment: You need to figure out which encoding was used to encode the file. Or try [other encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) at random. `'latin_1'` or the `'iso8859_XX'` variants might work but it woud mean there are control characters in your file.

Comment: without the csv-file its hard to help, I switch of now .. good luck.

Comment: Take a loke here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000253/300130, as @goyo mentioned, the data is not encoded utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the encoding argument to read_csv as well

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/kiya/sep_sent.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: It shows that same error

Comment: Looks like you have non unicode characters in your text. See @Goyo's answer in comments above. To find out where the issue is in the file, you might want to consider chunking up the file into smaller units to identify which unit the problem is in

Answer (score -1):

Open the file with utf-8 encoding and it should work:

```
with open("/Users/kiya/sep_sent.csv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in f: 
       print(i.strip())
```

Comment: Actually the error message is saying that `utf-8` doesn't work.

Comment: It shows that same error

Comment: OK, but now the you get output `0` before it was `b0` which was binray zero, now you got string character `0` .. compare https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52627668/revisions

Comment: ya but It is not running completely and an error is displayed

Comment: It seems your terminal is using `cp1252` (see traceback) and in the csv file there are chracters which are not printable on such a codepage.

Comment: Is it possible to skip that values? Since the CSV file is large in capacity and can not be opened in Excel

Comment: @return42 The traceback says that the error is triggered by `for i in f:` so when reading the file not when printing.

Comment: @goyo: there is a print at this point and this print statement is (now) causing the excepition .. typical encoding mistakes

Comment: @return42 I don't understand what you mean, I cannot see `print` in the tracebacks. They clearly say that `for i in f:` is the user code that triggers the error.

Comment: @goyo: sorry, my mistake .. the example was edited so often, I lost control ;)