# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 11: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I am trying to convert all csv files of a folder to xlsx and using below code.

```
import glob
import csv
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob('D:\cf111\*.csv')
for k in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(k)
    df.to_excel("abc.xlsx")
```

The code is generating the below error.

`utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 11: invalid start byte`

I cant sort out, how to resolve this error.

Comment: use raw string when you have backslashes `r'D:\cf111\*.csv'`

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the exception you are getting.

Comment: This means the file is *not* UTF8. Perhaps it's Latin1 with a fancy quote, like the duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000191/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x92-in-position-18-invalid-start-byte)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might because there are contents in the csv that do not support encoding="utf-8". you can try using **other encoding** though.

code example:

```
import glob
import csv
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob('D:\cf111\*.csv')
for k in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(k, encoding='ISO 8859-1')
    df.to_excel("abc.xlsx")
```

***document reference:***
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Thank you. The encoding problem is resolved. but it only converts one(first) file. Does not run through the whole folder to check other files.

Comment: You need to change your excel file names each time the **for loop** executes the loop. Else, only your **last** csv will be converted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ISO 8859-1** encoding instead of 'utf-8', for example

```
msg = email.message_from_string(str(arr[1],  'ISO 8859-1'))
```