# Loading data from a .txt with load_dataset

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I have a .txt with a bunch of text that I'm going to use for finetuning a Large Language Model. I want to load that dataset using load_dataset.

I have tried to do what the documentation online and some other GitHub issues advised me to do, which is this:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset

path= r'myfile.txt'
test = load_dataset("text", data_files=path)
```

This code block results in the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last) File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py:1917, in ArrowBasedBuilder._prepare_split_single(self, gen_kwargs, fpath, file_format, max_shard_size, job_id) 1916 _time = time.time() 1917 for _, table in generator: 1918     if max_shard_size is not None and writer._num_bytes > max_shard_size:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\packaged_modules\text\text.py:89, in Text._generate_tables(self, files) 88 while True: 89     batch = f.read(self.config.chunksize) 90     if not batch:

File <frozen codecs>:322, in decode(self, input, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 241: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatasetGenerationError                    Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[29], line 2 1 path= r'C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Office 365 Fontys\AIDNDDB-Final.txt' 2 test = load_dataset("text", data_files=path) 3 encodings = tokenizer("\n\n".join(test["text"]), return_tensors="pt")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\load.py:2152, in load_dataset(path, name, data_dir, data_files, split, cache_dir, features, download_config, download_mode, verification_mode, ignore_verifications, keep_in_memory, save_infos, revision, token, use_auth_token, task, streaming, num_proc, storage_options, **config_kwargs) 2149 try_from_hf_gcs = path not in _PACKAGED_DATASETS_MODULES 2151 # Download and prepare data 2152 builder_instance.download_and_prepare( 2153     download_config=download_config, 2154     download_mode=download_mode, 2155     verification_mode=verification_mode, 2156     try_from_hf_gcs=try_from_hf_gcs, 2157     num_proc=num_proc, 2158     storage_options=storage_options, 2159 ) 2161 # Build dataset for splits 2162 keep_in_memory = ( 2163     keep_in_memory if keep_in_memory is not None else is_small_dataset(builder_instance.info.dataset_size) 2164 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py:948, in DatasetBuilder.download_and_prepare(self, output_dir, download_config, download_mode, verification_mode, ignore_verifications, try_from_hf_gcs, dl_manager, base_path, use_auth_token, file_format, max_shard_size, num_proc, storage_options, **download_and_prepare_kwargs) 946     if num_proc is not None: 947         prepare_split_kwargs["num_proc"] = num_proc 948     self._download_and_prepare( 949         dl_manager=dl_manager, 950         verification_mode=verification_mode, 951         **prepare_split_kwargs, 952         **download_and_prepare_kwargs, 953     ) 954 # Sync info 955 self.info.dataset_size = sum(split.num_bytes for split in self.info.splits.values())

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py:1043, in DatasetBuilder._download_and_prepare(self, dl_manager, verification_mode, **prepare_split_kwargs) 1039 split_dict.add(split_generator.split_info) 1041 try: 1042     # Prepare split will record examples associated to the split 1043     self._prepare_split(split_generator, **prepare_split_kwargs) 1044 except OSError as e: 1045     raise OSError( 1046         "Cannot find data file. " 1047         + (self.manual_download_instructions or "") 1048         + "\nOriginal error:\n" 1049         + str(e) 1050     ) from None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py:1805, in ArrowBasedBuilder._prepare_split(self, split_generator, file_format, num_proc, max_shard_size) 1803 job_id = 0 1804 with pbar: 1805     for job_id, done, content in self._prepare_split_single( 1806         gen_kwargs=gen_kwargs, job_id=job_id, **_prepare_split_args 1807     ): 1808         if done: 1809             result = content

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py:1950, in ArrowBasedBuilder._prepare_split_single(self, gen_kwargs, fpath, file_format, max_shard_size, job_id) 1948     if isinstance(e, SchemaInferenceError) and e.__context__ is not None: 1949         e = e.__context__ 1950     raise DatasetGenerationError("An error occurred while generating the dataset") from e 1952 yield job_id, True, (total_num_examples, total_num_bytes, writer._features, num_shards, shard_lengths)

DatasetGenerationError: An error occurred while generating the dataset
```

I also tried other combinations, like:

```
dataset = load_dataset("text", data_files={"train": "path", "test": "path"})
```

If there are any details that I didn't include and that you deem necessary to help me, let me know.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It looks like myfile.txt is not encoded in UTF8.

Comment: Scpecify library from which you import `load_dataset` function

Comment: huggingface.datasets @VZ

Comment: may be you need specify delimeter
load_dataset("text", data_files=path_to_file, delimiter=delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I assume your file is not saved as `utf-8`. In this case, you need to specify the encoding of the file with the respective [encoding](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.15.0/en/package_reference/loading_methods#datasets.packaged_modules.text.TextConfig) parameter. Since 0x92 is a `’` in cp1252 (compare this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000253/6664872)), the following should work:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset

path= r'myfile.txt'
test = load_dataset("text", data_files=path, encoding='cp1252')
```

Comment: Works, I had the same error. `test['train']['text']` will have the text of the file. The shell shows: `Downloading and preparing dataset text/default to myuserpath/.cache/huggingface/datasets/text/default-123abc...

Dataset text downloaded and prepared to myuserpath/.cache/huggingface/datasets/text/default-123abc. Subsequent calls will reuse this data.`

Comment: This 'cp1252' encoding cannot cope with German umlauts. Strangely, after having loaded it with 'cp1252' and finding the wrong umlaut placeholders, and then afer switching back to 'utf-8', it ran through without an error. And when I then dropped the parameter, it also ran through. It still might help to follow this answer, but I guess that making a cold restart by loading anything again might fix it as well.